# Screen recording in iphone

Tags: iphone, screen, screen-capture

I want to make a screen recorder with iphone.
Is it possible to do that?

If yes how can i implement a screen recorder with xcode, anybody can help me.
I know how to implement(i mean the logic),that is add pictures to a video file in a regular interval.but how can i do this with iphone sdk

Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean a standard iPhone which is not jailbroken:

No, you can't. You could write an app that captured images of its own display when running, but you can't capture the screen in general (e.g. the home screen, or other apps' screens). It's not the sort of software Apple would allow, even if you found a way to hack around it (which I imagine wouldn't be possible).

Comment: No no i don't want capture homescreen or any other applications screen.

Comment: No no i don't want capture homescreen or any other application's screen.Just record portion of my apps screen. I know how to capture it as an image but don't know how to make it as a video

Answer (score -1):

What about this? It seems to indicate that video screen capture and saving (using the UIGetScreenImage function) is now allowed by Apple.

http://www.tuaw.com/2009/12/15/apple-relents-and-is-now-allowing-uigetscreenimage-for-app-st/